# How to restrict the price to 2 decimal points

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal, tofixed

My Html

```
<div class="product-line">              
                    <a href="#" alt="close" class="btn-close" title="Remove"><img alt="remove" src="img/close.png" /></a>
                    <input class="input-text" name="product-code" type="text" placeholder="Product Code" />
                    <input class="input-text" name="product-quantity" type="text" placeholder="Quantity" />
                    <input class="input-text" name="product-discript" type="text" placeholder="Discription of Product" disabled />
                    <label class="label-sign">&pound;</label>
                    <input class="input-text price" name="product-price" type="text" placeholder="RRP Price" disabled />
                        <br>
</div>
```

My JS code line

```
price = $(this).parent("div.product-line").find("input[name=product-price]").val( Number(price).toFixed(2)  *  quantity )
```

Basically if I multiply for example 40.2  quantity 3, i get something like 120.600000000.... How can i restrict it to 2 decimal points.

The data is coming in via JSON (made by someone else).

I am a JS newbie

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript

Comment: Doesn't google work for you???

Comment: The OP is already using toFixed, it's just in the wrong place, so it's not really a duplicate.

Comment: @adeneo My bad really! I didn't saw it :(

Comment: @A.Wolff - I was really anwering the first comment, duplicate of "how to round numbers", I guess Google would have worked if you'd search for toFixed and read the MDN docs.

Comment: @adeneo Ya but then i wouldn't have posted a so rude comment. Even i keep it for History ;)

Comment: @All-the-above! I thought that's what the SO is for - to help others to learn and to better what we know and love to do!!! Why voting down the guy. He already said that he's a newbie. If you don't want to help and you don't care, just skip the question and work/answer something that's for you like a Featured question! Sometimes for a newbie things might get too overwhelming or confusing. Don't judge, but help!

Comment: @Thank you everyone for all the comments and help! I even appreciate negative comments as it help better my skills.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move `toFixed` to the output of the multiplication instead.

```
.val( ( Number(price) *  quantity ).toFixed(2) );
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not exactly sure why it was not working.

Comment: Can you also tell me why this --- Number( $("input[name=order-total]").val(sum) ).toFixed(2); --- is not working, Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not working because `val(sum)` returns the jQuery object, which has no toFixed method. You have to convert the passed in value, as in `val( sum.toFixed(2) )`

Comment: Thank you! I managed to figure it out using your example, but now I understand why. Thnaks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var price = $(this).parent("div.product-line").find("input[name=product-price]").val(( Number(price) * quantity ).toFixed(2));
```

Comment: Thank you, Help most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First multiply then use to fixed...

```
price = $(this).parent("div.product-line").find("input[name=product-price]").val( Number(price)  *  quantity ).toFixed(2)
```

**jQuery to round off decimal values**

The toFixed() method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.

```
var iNum = 12345.6789;
iNum.toFixed();    // Returns "12346": note rounding, no fractional part
iNum.toFixed(1);   // Returns "12345.7": note rounding
iNum.toFixed(6);   // Returns "12345.678900": note added zeros
```

The toPrecision() method formats a number to a specified length.

```
var iNum = 5.123456;
iNum.toPrecision();    // Returns 5.123456
iNum.toPrecision(5);   // Returns 5.1235
iNum.toPrecision(2);   // Returns 5.1
iNum.toPrecision(1);   // Returns 5
```

But then you will be wondering how toPrecision() is different from toFixed()? Well, they are different.toFixed() gives you a fixed number of decimal places, whereas the other gives you a fixed number of significant digits.

```
var iNum = 15.667;
iNum.toFixed(2);        // Returns "15.67"
iNum.toPrecision(2);    // Returns "16"
iNum.toPrecision(3);    // Returns "15.7"
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do if you are OK with slight rounding (sounds like you won't be but might as well give multiple suggestions), is to wrap your result in toFixed

```
(Number(price) * quantity).toFixed(2)
```

but, really, if you need precision for floating point numbers you should looking into something like [bigDecimal.js](https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js)

Comment: Thank you! Help most appreciated.